# What is the graph of the function $y = \frac{x}{1+ |x|}$?

Tags: functions

In this question , multiple concepts of graphical transformations are involved. I am facing problems in applying all of them in a single question.

Answer (score 1):

$$|a|=\begin{cases}a, a\ge 0\\ -a, a<0\end{cases}$$

If $x\ge0$ then $$y=\frac x{1+x}=\frac {1+x-1}{1+x}=1-\frac 1{1+x} -$$ hyperbola

If $x<0$ then $$y=\frac x{1-x}=-\frac {1-x-1}{1-x}=-1+\frac 1{1-x} -$$ hyperbola

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The [graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_of_a_function) of your function is by definition the set
$$\left\{\left(x,\frac{x}{1+|x|}\right):x\in\Bbb R\right\}\subseteq\Bbb R^2.$$